# Workbench moderation and check permissions tab

Tags: workbench

Reading through the workbench_moderation module readme file I came across this:

For reference, these are the permission sets recommended by the "Check 
Permissions" tab:

```
Author:
  Node:
    access content
    view own unpublished content
    view revisions
    create [content type] content
    edit own [content type] content
  Workbench Moderation:
    view moderation messages
    use workbench_moderation my drafts tab
```

However, going to /admin/config/workbench/moderation/check-permissions on my drupal 7 instance, when I select the drupal role of editor, I don't see any of the options listed in the readme file (as above).

All I see is, Moderation task dropdown menu, and then a list of Content types (which I previously enabled in the structure section)

Why am I missing all these options in the Check permissions tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing the permissions, just looking in the wrong spot. Log in as an admin user and head over to `yoursite.com/admin/people/permissions`. This is the main permissions management page which shows all permissions defined by all modules.

You'll see 'sections' of permissions defined by various modules. There will be 'Node' and 'Workbench Moderation' sections mentioned in the file you read, as well as the relevant permissions.